# What is the recommended default index fill factor for Sitecore CMS and OMS SQL database indexes?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sitecore, sitecore6

We're running Sitecore 6.4 with OMS on SQL Server 2008. I've seen blogs with Sitecore index rebuilding scripts where it explicitly uses a fill factor of 80 in the script. What is the official Sitecore recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Cassidy says above, the OMS tuning guide uses figures like 80 and 90% throughout the script examples. This isn't included in the CMS Performance Tuning guide though.

Sitecore support suggest that the precise fill factor to use can vary with index, database, and the precise implementation and usage of the application. Values between 50-75% were suggested as feasible, depending on performance.

In particular, the Sitecore analytics database - which performs limited read operations and a huge amount of write operations - can have indexes with a far lower fill factor than the CMS databases. Indexes with a lower fill factor are slower to read due to the amount of empty pages.

While a ballpark figure of 80% is a reasonable starting point, this should be tested index by index by watching fragmentation rate and measuring the performance of read operations.

The frequency and cost of index rebuilds must also be factored in.

With a low fill factor the indexes will be minimally fragmented for longer periods, requiring fewer scheduled rebuilds, but may be read more slowly. With a high fill factor the indexes will become fragmented far faster, requiring more frequent scheduled rebuilds, but will offer better read performance while not fragmented.

Answer (score 3):

FILLFACTOR 80 and 90 are used consistently throughout the OMS Performance Tuning Guide (http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/OMS%20Performance%20Tuning%20Guide.aspx). I'd say that's pretty much as close to an official Sitecore recommendation that we're going to get.

Comment: I just got a reply from Sitecore support which suggested anything between 50-75% for the CMS and possibly as low as 25% on frequently updated (but seldom read) indexes in the OMS. The disclaimer was that this all comes under the heading "application specific tuning" - so test what works, adjust how often you rebuild indexes and find the best balance.

Comment: Heh yes; I think the key term here is "application specific tuning". Which would explain why Sitecore doesn't explicitly state much in their cookbooks on this.

Comment: I tried to flesh out your answer but unfortunately my edit didn't make it through the review process, so I posted it myself.